How to delete a specific line containing a file path from a text file in Linux using a variable with this path?
I need to delete a specific line from the fstab file, given the Mountpoint in $MOUNTPOINT variable:
So, I have this variable:
MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/my_lvm_partition

when I tried to find it in fstab file:
grep $MOUNTPOINT /etc/fstab

the output came as following:
/dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv /mnt/my_lvm_partition ext4 rw 0 0

I'm trying to delete this line from fstab file using this command:
sed -i "/$MOUNTPOINT/d" /etc/fstab

but it gives this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `m'
So, I tried to change the delimiter as following:
sed -i "|$MOUNTPOINT|d" /etc/fstab

but gives me this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'

You need to use: sed -i "\|$MOUNTPOINT|d" /etc/fstab

Solved, thanks to anubhava:
I used the escape character \ before the delimiter |
sed -i "\|$MOUNTPOINT|d" /etc/fstab


That would fail in various ways given various values of MOUNTPOINT (e.g. if it contained regexp metachars or was a substring of some other string in fstab), YMMV using it.

Don't use all upper case variable names for non-exported variables (see Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization) and don't do a full line regexp match when what you need is a full-field string match (see How do I find the text that matches a pattern?).
This will do what you show in your question much more robustly than your sed script:
mountpoint=/mnt/my_lvm_partition

mp="$mountpoint" awk -i inplace '$2 != ENVIRON["mp"]' /etc/fstab

That's more robust because:

Use of a lower case variable name means we won't accidentally overwrite the value of an environment variable.
It's targeting just the field you apparently want to match on so you won't get a false match from the fields, comments in the file, etc.
It's doing a litertal string instead of regexp match so you won't get false matches if your mountpoint name contains .s or other regexp metachars.
It's doing a full-field instead of partial-line match so you won't get false matches if your mountpoint name can appear as a substring for some other path.
It doesn't require any particular characters (e.g. |s) to not be present in your mountpoint name other than spaces since it's isolating the 2nd space-separated field but your fstab wouldn't work as-is if you had that (if your mountpoint name can contain spaces there are various tweaks possible to accomodate that).

It's using GNU awk for -i inplace, which I assume you have since you're using GNU sed for that syntax of -i.
